# Serving /home/[user]/http/[domain] using vhost results in 403

Tags: apache, file-permissions, http-status-code-403, vhosts

Commenting out `httpd-vhosts.conf` and browsing goes to the default directory `/srv/http` with no problems.

*/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:*

```
<VirtualHost test.loc:80>
    ServerName test.loc
    ServerAlias www.test.loc
    DocumentRoot /home/shane/http/test.loc

    <Directory /home/shane/http/test.loc>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

All files and folders are readable and executable: `chmod -R 755 /home/shane/http`, but are still owned by me.

Answer (score -1):

Needed to `chmod 755 /home/shane`.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer So should I never serve html from my home directory? Or maybe just executable?

Comment: Its totally fine to serve html from a sub directory of your home dir. Making /home/shane/http globally readable it absolutely fine. But whatever the issues are that it doesn't work; Solving it by making your home dir globally readable is a bad idea.